# Can't get MAMP to load xdebug (phpinfo())

Tags: mamp, xdebug, phpstorm

MAC OSX 10.7.5 -- MAMP 2.1.3 -- XDEBUG 2.2.3
I used the [xdebug wizzard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) to download and install using the terminal. After following the steps
Rebooted MAMP but no xdebug in `phpinfo();`
I thought it was weird that the wizzard says all you have to do it paste `zend_extension = /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so` in the end of your php.ini file

- I did add quotes around the pathname - the pathname from the wizzard came without them
- Every other tutorial says there is more than just this one line that needs to be added
- MAMP seems to have its own 'zend_extension = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"' that just needs to becommented out. Anyway I tried both the pasting from the wizzard as well as uncommenting.

Since I'm trying to use xdebug with my PHPstorm trial, I checked for the steps layed you at http://www.dotvoid.com/2012/09/using-xdebug-in-mamp/
Again it's weird: Here it says that all you need to do it add these 2 lines

```
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1  

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

It's weird because other tutorials make you add more lines (back when I tried to get xdebug on an older version of MAMP to go with netbeans without success) about the localhost. 
Here's what's in my php.ini file now:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension= "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

I also checked if I'm configuring the right php.ini file, looking in phpinfo(); where it says which php.ini file is loaded. In this case `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini` I verified if this is the correct php.ini file that I'm edititing and it is.

The last anwser in this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608824/how-to-get-xdebug-to-work-on-a-mac) speaks of two certain files that need to be the same binary maybe one file is 32bit binary and the other one is 64bit. When I tried to check this, the files mentioned in that question (`/path/to/mamp/Library/modules/php5.3/libphp5.so`)  are not in my current installation of MAMP. In my current installation, I can go to `Applications/MAMP/Library/modules`, but there is no folder in that `modules` folder, leave alone one that says `php` of any sort.

In [this tutorial](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/436626?tstart=0), there is a mention of updating PEARL. This may not be relevant to my issue but I just followed it because I don't know really, I thought it wouldn't hurt. When I try to do that in my terminal the error message says

`Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
The Zend Engine API version 220100525 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api for a later version of Xdebug.`

I found this issue in the xdebug FAQ. I quote

> it is most likely because you compiled Xdebug against PHP headers that belong to a different PHP version that you're running

Further explanation confirms that the message about the zend api version points to the same issue and that two versions of PHP are colliding somehow.

The solution to this is explained on the same FAQ page where it says

> **Q: How do I find which phpize to use?** [...]If it doesn't match up, and perhaps the wrong "phpize" binary is found on the path, you can
>   run configure as follows:
>   1. /full/path/to/php/bin/phpize
>   2. ./configure --with-php-config=/full/path/to/php/bin/php-config

I don't know how to interpret this in practice. But here's what I have tried

- I was still in the `/usr/bin` and tried the first command `usr/bin/phize`. this returned `Cannot find config.m4. Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module`
  I don't know what they mean by the top level source directory of the module. Maybe 1. and 2. are 1 command? And the module means xdebug.so?

No matter what I try though, I keep getting the `Cannot find config.m4` error whenever I just even try to run phpize. I tried running phpize from `/usr/bin/phpize` or from `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/phpize`. Same error came

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after making changes? In any case: here is good manual: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/436626?tstart=0

Comment: Oh yes I certainly have rebooted the sever several times. Start/stop servers on MAMP that is; one other thing that I tried was `sudo apachectl restart` but also no success. Thank you for the tutorial!

Comment: The tutorial now led me back to something I was fiddling with at an earlier stage of my xdebug adventure. It confirms that there is an issue I thought I could afford to not look at but can't. I'll update my question

Comment: @Immers Did you have any further luck with this as I seem to be having the very same issue?

Comment: @jonnieM no unfortunately. Good to know I'm not alone in this though. Must admit I haven't been able to look into this any further due to time constraint